# Correct way to handle database errors in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, software-design

I have doubts about how to implement certain things in a Django Rest API (I'm using DRF), and I want to ask you for guidelines.

Imagine two models, for example, Employee, and Department. Each employee belongs to a Department, so the model should contain a foreign key in Employee pointing to the Department to which he belongs.

We cannot save an Employee if we do not assign a valid Department. So, the scenarios we need to handle are, from  the top of my head:

1. An Employee with no Department
2. An Employee with an invalid Department

Now, because this is a REST API, I assume that the data that feeds the application came from the POST call. So, both scenarios can be represent as:

```
bad_payload = {
       "employee_name": "John Doe",
}

inconsistent_payload = {
       "employee_name": "John Doe",
       ...
       "department": "Invalid Department"
}
```

Assuming Invalid Department is not on the database.

So, my questions:

1. Would the view be the best place to validate, or would it be better to trust the error that the database will throw when trying to insert the data into the table? (Remember, the foreign key has the NOT NULL restriction.
2. If the validation is done on the model, how can I bubble up the error so I can return a response with an error message to the client instead of crashing the application?
3. How can I handle the second scenario if the view is the right place to validate? Won't be the call to the database a violation of the separation of concerns?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a way to "bubble up" the response

Answer (score 0):

Using DRF's serializers is best for this.

```
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Employee

class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = [
            "name",
            "department",
            # other fields ...
        ]


    def validate(self, data):
        name = data["name"]
        department = data.get("department")

        # do some validation, like
        if not is_valid_department(department, name):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid department")

        return data
```

Then in the view

```
# views.py
from rest_framework import views, response
from .serializers import EmployeeSerializer

class MyApiView(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = EmployeeSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return response.Response(serializer.data, status=201)
```

exceptions raised from `serializers.ValidationError` will be handled by DRF, it will return a status 400 and the data passed in the exception instead of a server error